# I want to save each element in this char array into a separate array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Okay so my input file looks like this:

```
Adam Zeller 45231 78 86 91 64 90 76 
Barbara Young 274253 88 77 91 66 82 93 
Carl Wilson 11223 87 77 76 78 77 82
```

I want to use the strtok() function to save the first and last name into one array and the numbers into I guess an int array, But I can't figure out how to ignore the first name and the last name when I am using strtok()

Could anyone help me out with this?

Also I can't use the string library, but I can use the cstring library

Comment: You don't need `strtok()` if you're doing this is C++.

Comment: Don't use `strtok` or C-style strings (char array).  Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Do not use `strtok`, there is `std::stringstream` does better job.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I can't use the <string> library :(

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read file parse" for examples of parsing (extracting variables from formatted files).

Comment: If you can't use the string library then why is this tagged C++?

Comment: One thing I forgot to add is that they are char arrays, like each line.

Comment: If you are putting the first & last name into an array you dont have to skip them (or anything else).  Loop thru `strtok` and put the first 2 parsed results in your first array and the remainder of fields into your int array.

Comment: You attempt is inherently wrong: Who is 'Jean Paul' and who is 'Jean Paul Belmondo'

Comment: Can we skip the c++ purity tests?  Sometimes you need to drop down to straight C and this is obviously a contrived example to force OP to do just that and learn how to handle such situations.

Comment: @duck Ah but that's the probably I am getting stuck and confused on writing the code to do that..

Comment: @duck Yeah pretty much,

Answer (score 0):

Your input format appears to be fixed to `<first name>` and `<last name>`, followed by seven numbers. If that's the case, you could read the data from a file stream instead of using C-style input and `strtok`:

```
int n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6;
string firstName, lastName;
...
// Now you can read the whole line with a single line of code:
myFileStream >> firstName >> lastName >> n0 >> n1 >> n2 >> n3 >> n4 >> n5 >> n6;
```

If the number of `int`s that follow `<first name>` and `<last name>` is not fixed, you can construct a `stringstream` from each line that you read from file, and use a nested loop to parse all your `int` numbers.

> I can't use the `<string>` library

If `string` is not allowed, you could still use `>>` with `char` arrays. It wouldn't be as safe, though. You can also use `fscanf`, like this:

```
int n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6;
char firstName[256], lastName[256];
...
fscanf(fd, "%255s%255s%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", firstName, lastName, &n0, &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5, &n6);
```

Note the size restrictions on the `%s`. You need them to avoid buffer overruns.

Comment: I wish it was that easy but I can't use the <string> library

Comment: @MattRay Can you use C++ style I/O, or is it out as well?

Comment: I mean I guess but it is c++ I just can't use the string library :(

Comment: @MattRay If you can use `>>`, you can replace `string xyz` with `char xyz[256]` or whatever is the size you prefer for your buffers. You would need to use `strcpy` and `malloc`s (or `strdup`) a lot to avoid the use of `std::string`, though.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the first name is separated by a space, so look for that first:

```
static const char example_text[] = "Adam Zeller 45231 78 86 91 64 90 76";
char * p_text = &example_text[0];
char * p_first_name = p_text;
char * p_surname = NULL;
```

One can use the [strchr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) function to find the position of the space after the first name:

```
unsigned int length_first_name = 0U;
p_surname = strchr(example_text, ' ');
if (p_surname != NULL)
{
  length_first_name = p_surname = p_first_name;
  p_surname++;
}
```

I prefer the `strchr` function over the `strtok` since `strtok` modifies the string.

**Edit 1: substring.**
The function [strstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) can be used to fetch or extract or copy a substring.

Be aware that your destination needs to have space for the substring plus room for the termination character.

Using your textbook or reference manual, study up on the C-style string functions.  Any good reference books will have these grouped together.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense but how would I assign Adam Zeller into one array and the rest of the numbers into an int array?

Comment: See my edit.  Also see `strcpy`, `strcat` and `strdup` functions.

Comment: Thinking out loud to myself, I would search for the 2nd space character, supplying a pointer to the position after the first space to the `strchr` function.